# What is the best way to use indexedDB on Vue3 (CLI)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, indexeddb

I usually search google for best practice on using certain language, plugin, and framework.

I can't find any tutorial on what is the best practice using indexedDB on VUE CLI. I actually am succesful at using it but I think my code is redundant. I am not sure if it's the best way of doing it. So what I did is I have created a script that executes when mounted.

```js
let dbPromise = await indexedDB.open('dbname', 3);

/* initialize `tbl_contact` */
dbPromise.onupgradeneeded = (event) =>
{
    let ldb = event.target.result;

    // Create `contact` database
    let objectStore = ldb.createObjectStore("contact", { keyPath: "uid" });
    objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
    objectStore.createIndex("status", "status", { unique: false });
    
    //.. and other database
};
```

Then whenever I want to do something on `contact`. I open it again, like when I'm inserting information into it.

```js
storeContact(contact)
{
  /* local db setup */
  var dbPromise = indexedDB.open('dbname');

  /* execute code on successful local db connection */
  dbPromise.onsuccess = () =>
  {
      let ldb             = dbPromise.result;
      let tx              = ldb.transaction('contact', "readwrite");
      let tbl_contact     = tx.objectStore("contact");

      /* insert contact to database */
      tbl_contact.put(contact);

      tx.oncomplete = () =>
      {
          ldb.close();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can call `ldb.close()` prior to waiting for the transaction to complete, it will implicitly wait until the transaction is completed before closing. You can call `close()` immediately after starting the final request in your transaction.

Comment: Thank for that @Josh